# A file is being ignore in a find command

Tags: find

My directory contains a number of files and I want to show only those not starting atm.

```
D:/elite/custom>find d:/elite/custom/test -print
d:/elite/custom/Test
d:/elite/custom/Test/001234.txt
d:/elite/custom/Test/abc123.txt
d:/elite/custom/Test/ATM001.txt
d:/elite/custom/Test/ATM002.txt
d:/elite/custom/Test/DEF111.rtf
d:/elite/custom/Test/wwww.txt
d:/elite/custom/Test/abc


D:/elite/custom>find d:/elite/custom/test -name "[!ATM]*" -print
d:/elite/custom/Test/001234.txt
d:/elite/custom/Test/DEF111.rtf
d:/elite/custom/Test/wwww.txt
```

why is it not picking up `d:/elite/custom/Test/abc123.txt`?

Comment: Is this some Windows environment with a case-insensitive filesystem?

Comment: That prompt looks very unusual for a UNIX-like system; what operating system is this?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of `-name` is a so-called **pattern**, which looks like a shell's "globbing" - wildcards, etc.. The syntax `[!ATM]*` means something very different from what you think it means - it means any name starting with any one character which isn't A, T or M.

The pattern `atm*` (note no brackets) matches any name starting with "atm". There is **no pattern** syntax to negate this and match names *not* starting with "atm". But, luckily, find does have a syntax to negate the match a "!" before the "-name" parameter (not inside the pattern!) negates the matching: `find . ! -name 'atm*'`.

Comment: And please note that if you want case-insensitive name (and your Windows (?) doesn't do this automatically), you can use "-iname" instead of "-name" to do case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

Because `[!ATM]` doesn't mean what you (apparently) think it means. It means "any one character that isn't an `A`, a `T` or a `M`".

It seems `find` supports quite a number of different regex-types, I don't know them all, but for a match suitable for your use, I wouldn't be optimistic.

You need what (in PCRE (perl compatible regular expression)-lingo) is called a (zero-width) negative look-ahead.

Comment: but that filename starts with an `a`, which is not `A`, `T` or `M`.

Comment: I did notice, I suppose something makes the match (or the filesystem) case-insensitive. The filename shown also start with "d:" indicating that they reside on a windows box, so there are several details I don't know, and wouldn't be surprised to see causing unusual behaviour. It desn't change that '[!ATM]' doesn't mean what was intended.

Comment: yes, I suppose it must be that

Comment: `find . ! -name "ATM*"` should do for them

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot that`find` could do the negating. Many shells treat the `!` specially, so escaping might be needed in you command.

Comment: `!` like that is actually ok. As the first word it would invert the exit status of a command (or pipeline), and it's used in e.g. extended globs (`!(foo)` in Bash/ksh), and as a trigger for history substitution, but those require something else too, not just the lone `!`. Even fish and tcsh seem to leave it as-is. (Related to `find`, older versions of fish eat a lone unquoted `{}`, mostly other shells don't. Still need to escape the semicolon for `-exec`)